# Using two internet connections

Tags: networking, firefox, google-chrome, proxy, mobile-broadband

Sometimes I work in place where I have free wifi, but it requires proxy - and it work only for http(s). In my work I need ssh sometimes. I bought a G4 card, but it has transfer limit so I would like to use G4 only for ssh, and in browser use proxy only. How to configure it properly on ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You should aim for a customized routing table. The way you describe your problem, you want the following:

- A route to the proxy which uses the WiFi interface
- A route to your ssh server which uses the G4 card
- A default route on either device, or none at all, as you are not expecting any
  connections to hosts other than these two, right?

I must confess I'm not much of a GUI user in things like these. I know you could set up the routing table like this using the [rourte](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/route.8.html) command line tool. You'd basically add a route to the specific target through the default gateway of the device in question. You could even write a script to automate the process, once you've worked out the commands to use.

I guess there are ways to achieve similar effects using the Ubuntu graphical user interface tools. Someone else might know that detail. Answers to questions bearing the [routing tag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/routing?sort=votes) might also provide useful information on that, although I haven't found a GUI tutorial on custom routes at my first glance.